# black edge on photo

Tags: nikon, photo-editing, troubleshooting

I have been using a Nikon D300s and using View NX2 to edit my photos. Since the last upload, when I try to edit a photo the lower part on a horizontal photo or the right side on a vertical photo becomes black. What could be causing this?

Here is an example:

[image: Example of photo with black part]

Comment: Closing since no example provided.

Comment: Maybe the OP asked the question right before going to bed for the night. Can't we give them a few hours to let them have a chance to see the suggestion for examples before summarily closing the question.

Comment: @Michael: No.  Bad questions need to be closed.  I see the OP has now provided a example, so the close votes will stop coming in.  This is how the system is supposed to work.  We can't not close crap because the OP abandoned the question, whether overnight or forever.

Comment: Very rarely do questions get improved once they are closed, especially questions from new users. In that case the system *doesn't* work as it should. It doesn't hurt a bit to give someone, especially a new user, a bit of time to respond to the request.

Comment: What does "Since the last upload," mean? Upload of what and whereto? Why does that occasion matter?

Comment: Please upload a NEF photograph which happens to have this problem. Yes it will be helpful. Refer to your manual to know how to make one.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like your shutter is wearing out and the second curtain is not resetting all the way.

Update: Now that you've shown us an example it appears the line is very regular which likely indicates either a problem with your sensor or with the data pipeline in your camera. When shutter issues manifest themselves they rarely produce perfectly level black bars.

Most sensors are read out from top to bottom of the image (bottom to top of the inverted image on the sensor as it sits inside the camera). So your missing data is at the end of the image file.

Comment: Slow second curtain would cause overexposure, not a black area.

Answer (score 2):

This could be a mechanical shutter problem or a electrical problem with the sensor.

If the shutter, then the second curtain isn't retracting all the way after exposure.  It's always covering the part of the frame where the black is.  Note that this is *not* due to the curtain being slow in closing.  That would create a overexposed area, not underexposed or black.

The other possibility is a problem with the sensor or its readout circuit.  This is more likely if the black area starts or ends exactly at a power of 2 pixels vertically.  If electrical, the transition from normal picture to black will be abrupt.  One row is fine, and the next is completely black.

Try when the camera is both warm and cold.  If the black area boundary moves up or down a little, or is fuzzy, then its a mechanical shutter problem.

If the problem is with the shutter, then there is at least some chance you can fix this yourself, depending on how careful you can be.  If electronic, then there is nothing you can do yourself.

Of course if it's still under warranty, then don't touch it and let Nikon fix it for you.  If not, the cost of repair may exceed or be a good fraction of the cost of replacement with a new camera.

Comment: There are pixels at the edge of the sensor that are clipped when converting from RAW, so you can't count on having a power of 2.

Answer (score -1):

As it is an editing issue, I believe it to be a problem with your editing software. Check that cropping is disabled. Maybe try importing your raw photos into another editor (I recommend RawTherapee) and see if the problem still occurs. If not, try resetting the settings in your editor.